# How do I make a dropdown menu like this in the Evernote app?

Tags: android, android-layout

When you click the middle icon in the action bar a dropdown menu appears:

[image]

How do I make one of these? `RelativeLayouts`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this article can be useful for you. http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/